# How to set ArrayAdapter for spinner in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to add items to spinner in fragment. But i am having problem with the context. Because in fragment there is no context. Here how i am doing

```
public class DetailFrag extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View scrollView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myscrollview , container, false);       
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) scrollView.findViewById(R.id.mylayout1);

        for (int i=0; i<questionList.size(); i++) {

            View verticalLinearLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistrow,  null);
            View horizontalLInearLaoyout = verticalLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.questionRow);
            TextView tv = (TextView) horizontalLInearLaoyout.findViewById(R.id.question);
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) horizontalLInearLaoyout.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

            //Problem: how to define this in fragment createFromResource(this,...)
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.options_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

            EditText editText = (EditText) verticalLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.txtMultiLine);

            String question = questionList.get(i).question;

            tv.setId(i);
            tv.setText(i + question);
            spinner.setId(i);
            editText.setId(i);

            linearLayout.addView(verticalLinearLayout);          
        }       
        return scrollView;  
    } //end of onCreateView()
} //end of class DetailFrag
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In fragments, context is not available the way you expected in your code. Instead of `this`, use the following:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    getActivity().getBaseContext(),
    R.array.options_array,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Comment: Why `.getBaseContext()`?

Answer (score 1):

Since there we are in a Fragment,'this', won't work thus:
Using getActivity().getBaseContext() should be used to replace 'this';

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
   (getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                listItems);
```

Note on older versions of Android there is getContext() which will return context of the fragment as well, but for new versions it might not return context. Thus using getActivity() you are turned a Activity which is a context.

We use getActivity() which gets the current activity you are in followed by getBaseContext() since there can be multiple Context initiated in the Activity. We want to get the one that the Activity itself uses.

Answer (score -1):

do something like :

```
private Context myContext = null;

public DetailFrag(Context ctx){
    myContext = ctx;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//...
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                myContext, R.array.options_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);


//  
}
```

Comment: i used this and it worked `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`.

Comment: @Basit never use the application context for creating controls! Better use the activity itself. With the application context you can leak the context quiet fast.